# C++0x way to replace for(int i;;) range loops with range-based for-loop

Tags: c++, foreach, for-loop, c++11

So I've been getting into the new C++ using GCC 4.6 which now has range-based for-loops. I've found this really nice for iterating over arrays and vectors.

For mainly aesthetic reasons I wondered if there was a way to use this to replace the standard

`for(int i = min; i < max; i++) {}`

with something like

`for(int& i : std::range(min, max)) {}`

Is there something natively built into the new C++ standard that allows me to do this? Or do I have to write my own range/iterator class?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977339/c-range-xrange-equivalent-in-stl-or-boost

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a range class in C++11 for use with range based for loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185437/is-there-a-range-class-in-c11-for-use-with-range-based-for-loops)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see it anywhere. But it would be rather trivial:

```
class range_iterator : public std::input_iterator<int, int> {
    int x;
public:
    range_iterator() {}
    range_iterator(int x) : x(x) {}
    range_iterator &operator++() { ++x; return *this; }
    bool operator==(const range_iterator &r) const { return x == r.x; }
    int operator*() const { return x; }
};
std::pair<range_iterator, range_iterator> range(int a, int b) {
    return std::make_pair(range_iterator(a), range_iterator(b));
}
```

should do the trick (off the top of my head; might need a little tweaking). Pair of iterators should already be range, so I believe you shouldn't need to define begin and end yourself.

Comment: You might as well make it template on the `Integer` type.

Comment: @Matthieu Yes, sure. The other question mentioned as duplicate above has some more advanced implementations.