# Can one iterate on [0, n-1] interval with C++11 range-based-for?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a range class in C++11 for use with range based for loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185437/is-there-a-range-class-in-c11-for-use-with-range-based-for-loops)

I.e. is there a standard range with iterator that will dereference to an integer?
I'm thinking about something like this:

```
for (int i : rangeTo(10)) { ... }
for (int i : rangeFromTo(10, 20)) { .... }
```

Comment: I would like to avoid allocating an array.

Comment: What's wrong with good ol' `for(int i=0; i<10;i++)`?

Comment: What is the advantage of that over `for(int i = 10; i < 20; ++i)`?

Comment: tskuzzy: possibility of getting space formatting wrong.

Comment: Daniel: possibility of getting inequality wrong.

Comment: Łukasz, no difference. Well, actually there is. With the classical for loop, I know whether I need a strict or weak inequality. With a range, I'd always have to check whether that includes the upper bound or not, as in Python.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Nonsense. I have yet to see any C or C++ system or library (which *isn't* interfacing with some scripting language) that doesn't use a half-open range. It is absolutely standard in C/C++. Standard algorithms do it. Boost.Range does it. Virtually every for loop over some range of numbers does it. It's so common that if you're not using a half-open range in C/C++, it's usually considered a code smell.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ah, then I didn't get the inequality wrong? I thought I had, per Łukasz's comment. And that would confuse me, since half open is what I'd expect.

Comment: @Daniel - You did get it slightly wrong. :-) Łukasz wants you to use `!=` for inequality, not `<`. We are picky around here!

Comment: @BoPersson Aha. Guess that makes sense for iterators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but there is `boost::irange`:

```
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>
...
for (auto i : boost::irange(10, 20))
{
    std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

and `boost::counting_range`

```
for (auto i : boost::counting_range(10, 20))
{
    std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

The difference is you can add a step, for `boost::irange(10, 20, 2)`.