# Idioms for iterating a sequential collection

Tags: c++, iteration

In modern C++, the idiom for iterating a sequential collection like string or vector when you only need the value of each element is short and elegant:

```
for (auto x: xs)
```

When you also need the index, it's a little less elegant:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i != xs.size() ++i)
```

... unless there's some recent development I haven't yet caught up with. Does C++11 have a preferred way of doing the latter, or is the above still as good as it gets?

Comment: What about use zip_iterator to zip your iterator with a counting_iterator? You can write a generic container wrapper class that works on iterators of this type.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185437/is-there-a-range-class-in-c11-for-use-with-range-based-for-loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred and idiomatic way is the simple for loop.

Alternative methods include using an integer range:

```
template<typename C>
auto container_index(C const& container) -> decltype(boost::irange(0, container.size())) {
  return boost::irange(0, container.size());
}

for(auto x : container_index(xs))
```

Or an iterating function:

```
template<typename F>
void index_iterate(std::size_t size, F func) {
  for(std::size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
    func(i);
  }
}

index_iterate(container.size(), [&](std::size_t i){ /* ... */ });
```

Just go with the simple loop whenever possible though. It's superior in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

`Range-Based for loops` will be very popular in the modern code, `Range-Based for Loops`
is valid for any type supporting the notion of a range.  Given object obj of type T, `begin(obj)` and `end(obj)` are valid.
Includes:

- All C++11 library containers.
- Arrays and valarrays.
- Initializer lists.
- Regular expression matches.
- Any UDT(user defined type) T where begin(T) and end(T) yield suitable iterators.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two methods:

```
int i = 0;
for ( auto x : v ) {
    // do smth with x or v[i] or i
    i++;
}
```