# Can a range-based for-loop be used with a constant integer value (C++11)

Tags: c++11, for-loop, foreach

So my question is simply, can something like this work:

```
int size = 100;
for(int i : size)
  // bla
```

And if not, could you briefly explain why?

Comment: No, what would you expect this to do? An `int` is not a collection... (specifically, it has no `begin()` and `end()` member functions, which would be the requirement for range-based for loops to work.)

Comment: Perhaps you want something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185437/is-there-a-range-class-in-c11-for-use-with-range-based-for-loops ?

Comment: @Nate Kohl that is perfect thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Range-based `for-loop` are introduced for iterating through a collection, not some arbitrary range. Running a loop for a range of values can be achieved by using `for`, `while` or `do-while`.
If you need such loop, for regular activities, that can be implemented by simply wring a function, a macro, that may take a function, functor, or lambda.

Answer (score 2):

No, that does not work. A number is not a range. How would you define `begin(100)` or `end(100)` (which is what the range-based for loop calls internally)?

My guess is you'd want this as a shorthand for a loop from `0` to `99`. But why not one from `-2147483648` (or whatever `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` is on your implementation) to `99`?

Answer (score 1):

No this will not work!

*Range-based loop* works only on collections, which `int` is not.

Moreover, if you are comparing it with a normal`for` loop, where is the *initialization* (`i=0`) statement and *comparison* (`i<size`) statement for `i`? The construct does not tell when to start the loop and when to end!