# How to make a range to use range based for (to replace traditional for)?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, c++14

I have the following loop in more then one place:

```
for(int step = 1; step < timesteps; step++) ...
```

Then I had to change timesteps to start at 0. And I have to change it in more then one place.

May I take advantage of range based for loops in this situation? So may be I can write just

```
for(auto &step : timesteps) ...
```

In that case what kind of timesteps should be used? std::vector timesteps?

Before I forget to mention, timesteps is just an int i.e. `int timesteps = 10;`. Unknown at compile time, the user will define it.

p.s.: stl is preferred over boost.

Comment: what is the declaration of `timesteps`?

Comment: Use your favourite range library, e.g. Boost.Range: `for(auto step : boost::irange(1, timesteps))` [Live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ntXRTROAWfja5rwt)

Comment: If `timesteps` is just an integer value, you can't use a range based for. There is no range in a single integer -- it is what it is and nothing more. (poet and didn't know it...) Technically, there is no `begin` or `end` for a single-integer.

Comment: You mean there is no similar to irange of boost in stl so far?

Comment: Related: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51523/simple-integer-range-for-c11-range-based-for-loops  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185437/is-there-a-range-class-in-c11-for-use-with-range-based-for-loops  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930096/c0x-way-to-replace-forint-i-range-loops-with-range-based-for-loop

Comment: what about defining: const int timesteps_begin = 1; and using that inside the initializer part of the for loop?

Comment: I was thinking about that. But range based for will be shorter.