# std::iota is very limited

Tags: c++, c++11

Coming from a `Python` world, I find the function [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) very limited. Why is the interface restricted to not take any `UnaryFunction` ?

For instance I can convert

```
>>> x = range(0, 10)
```

into

```
std::vector<int> x(10);
std::iota(std::begin(x), std::end(x), 0);
```

But how would one do:

```
>>> x = range(0,20,2)
```

or even

```
>>> x = range(10,0,-1)
```

I know this is trivial to write one such function or use Boost, but I figured that C++ committee must have picked this design with care. So clearly I am missing something from C++11.

Comment: You can use `std::transform` if you want to do some other operation over a vector.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1977339/2301450

Comment: Have a look at std::generate, but the bottom line is that there isn't a really elegant standard library solution in c++ yet.

Comment: `iota` is a simple function for simple needs. For more complex needs, `generate` or `transform` is available.

Comment: I find python's `range` vexing, it changes the meaning of it's positional arguments based on how many there are. That the equivalent functionality is split between `iota` and `generate` (+ a lambda) is a plus to me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> But how would one do:
>
> ```
> x = range(0,20,2)
> ```

Alternatively to `std::generate()` (see other answer), you can provide your own unary function to `std::iota()`, it just have to be called `operator++()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
struct IotaWrapper
{
    typedef T type;
    typedef std::function<type(const type&)> IncrFunction;

    type value;
    IncrFunction incrFunction;

    IotaWrapper() = delete;
    IotaWrapper(const type& n, const IncrFunction& incrFunction) : value(n), incrFunction(incrFunction) {};

    operator type() { return value; }
    IotaWrapper& operator++() { value = incrFunction(value); return *this; }
};

int main()
{
    IotaWrapper<int> n(0, [](const int& n){ return n+2; });
    std::vector<int> v(10);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), n);

    for (auto i : v)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

**Output**: `0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18`

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e6cd544b8d512f3)</kbd>

---

Here is an idea of how one could implement `Range()`:

```
struct Range
{
    template<class Value, class Incr>
    std::vector<Value> operator()(const Value& first, const Value& last, const Incr& increment)
    {
        IotaWrapper<Value> iota(first, [=](const int& n){ return n+increment; });
        std::vector<Value> result((last - first) / increment);
        std::iota(result.begin(), result.end(), iota);
        return result;
    }
};
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4553e7f8800dab10)</kbd>

Answer (score 37):

how about [`std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate)?

```
int n = -2;
std::generate(x.begin(), x.end(), [&n]{ return n+=2; }); 
int n = 10;
std::generate(x.begin(), x.end(), [&n]{ return n--;});
```

Comment: However this may fix the problem in the question, I think author was asking about `std::iota` overload to something like `std::iota(std::begin(x), std::end(x), 0, 2)` where `2` is a step of iteration - why c++11 does not have one like it. So this question in my opinion is more to c++ standard commitee.

Answer (score 7):

With C++20 ranges, you can write it like this:

```cpp
static auto stepped_iota(int start, int step) {
  return std::ranges::views::iota(0) |
         std::ranges::views::transform([=](int x) { return x * step + start; });
}

void f() {
  for (int x : stepped_iota(0, 2)) { ... }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/3G49rs

Or, if you want the range to be finite:

```cpp
static auto stepped_iota(int start, int end, int step) {
  return std::ranges::views::iota(0, (end - start + step - 1) / step) |
         std::ranges::views::transform([=](int x) { return x * step + start; });
}
```