# Is there any equivalent of Python range() in C++?

Tags: c++, c++20

I want to use `std::for_each` to iterate over vector indexes in range `[a, b)` in parallel, calculate the value of the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) and write it to the `std::vector`:

```cpp
std::vector<std::array<float, 2>> values(1000);
auto range = /** equivalent of Pyhthon range(0, values.size()) **/;

std::for_each(std::execution::par, range.begin(), range.end(), [&](auto &&i) {
    values[i][0] = static_cast<float>(i) / resolution;
    values[i][1] = weierstrass(a, b, static_cast<float>(i) / resolution);
});

// a, b, and resolution are some constants defined before
// weierstrass() is the Weierstrass function
```

I have found some solutions in the internet, but all of them requires to include some third-party libraries or create my own range class. Is there any standard solution for this?

Comment: Does `std::iota` do what you want?

Comment: You can use `std::ranges::for_each(std::views::iota(1, 10), LAMBDA);`, as [in this code](https://godbolt.org/z/WGhhWTvfs), put a look.

Comment: `std::views::iota` is an option, but unfortunately, it [doesn't currently work with the C++17 parallel algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71587975/parallel-for-loop-with-stdfor-each-and-stdviewsiota/71588682#71588682).

Comment: Just updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71706148/941531) to also solve issue with `std::execution::par` which you used, please put a look at second code snippet.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34544665/5470596 (not a duplicate)

Comment: Shameless plug: https://github.com/klmr/cpp11-range

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [std::views::iota()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view), its use is similar (but a bit different) to Python's `range()`. With help of [std::ranges::for_each()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/for_each). Both are available in C++20.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/GaerraxYG)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::ranges::for_each(std::views::iota(1, 10), [](int i) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    });
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

---

As [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71705990/is-there-any-equivalent-of-python-range-in-c/71706148?noredirect=1#comment126725116_71706148) by @Afshin, in code mentioned above `std::ranges::for_each()` doesn't support `std::execution::par` for multi-threaded execution.

To overcome this issue you may use iota with regular `std::for_each()` as following:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/hrGW33c8P)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>
#include <execution>

int main() {
    auto range = std::views::iota(1, 10);
    std::for_each(std::execution::par, range.begin(), range.end(),
        [](int i) {
            std::cout << i << ' ';
        });
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

---

I decided to implement `Range` class plus iterator from scratch, according to how it works in Python's `range()`.

Similar to Python you can use it three ways: `Range(stop)`, `Range(start, stop)`, `Range(start, stop, step)`. All three support any negative value.

To test correctness of implementation I filled two unordered sets, one containing all generated values, another containing all used thread ids (to show that it actually used multi-core CPU execution).

Although I marked my iterator as random access type, still it is missing some methods like `-=` or `--` operators, these extra methods are for further improvements. But for usage of `std::for_each()` it has enough methods.

If I made some mistakes of implementation please add comments to my answer with explanation.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/9b1ccsr1W)

```cpp
#include <limits>
#include <execution>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <thread>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <mutex>

class Range {
public:
    Range(ptrdiff_t start_stop, ptrdiff_t stop =
            std::numeric_limits<ptrdiff_t>::max(), ptrdiff_t step = 1)
        : step_(step) {
        if (stop == std::numeric_limits<ptrdiff_t>::max()) {
            start_ = 0;
            stop_ = start_stop;
        } else {
            start_ = start_stop;
            stop_ = stop;
        }
        if (step_ >= 0)
            stop_ = std::max(start_, stop_);
        else
            stop_ = std::min(start_, stop_);
        if (step_ >= 0)
            stop_ = start_ + (stop_ - start_ + step_ - 1) / step_ * step_;
        else
            stop_ = start_ - (start_ - stop_ + step_ - 1) / (-step_) * (-step_);
    }
    class RangeIter {
    public:
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = ptrdiff_t;
        using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;
        using pointer = ptrdiff_t const *;
        using reference = ptrdiff_t const &;

        RangeIter() {}
        RangeIter(ptrdiff_t start, ptrdiff_t stop, ptrdiff_t step)
            : cur_(start), stop_(stop), step_(step) {}
        RangeIter & operator += (ptrdiff_t steps) {
            cur_ += step_ * steps;
            if (step_ >= 0)
                cur_ = std::min(cur_, stop_);
            else
                cur_ = std::max(cur_, stop_);
            return *this;
        }
        RangeIter operator + (ptrdiff_t steps) const {
            auto it = *this;
            it += steps;
            return it;
        }
        ptrdiff_t operator [] (ptrdiff_t steps) const {
            auto it = *this;
            it += steps;
            return *it;
        }
        ptrdiff_t operator - (RangeIter const & other) const {
            return (cur_ - other.cur_) / step_;
        }
        RangeIter & operator ++ () {
            *this += 1;
            return *this;
        }
        ptrdiff_t const & operator * () const {
            return cur_;
        }
        bool operator == (RangeIter const & other) const {
            return cur_ == other.cur_;
        }
        bool operator != (RangeIter const & other) const {
            return !(*this == other);
        }
        ptrdiff_t cur_ = 0, stop_ = 0, step_ = 0;
    };
    auto begin() const { return RangeIter(start_, stop_, step_); }
    auto end() const { return RangeIter(stop_, stop_, step_); }
private:
    ptrdiff_t start_ = 0, stop_ = 0, step_ = 0;
};

int main() {
    ptrdiff_t start = 1, stop = 1000000, step = 2;
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::unordered_set<std::string> threads;
    std::unordered_set<ptrdiff_t> values;
    auto range = Range(start, stop, step);
    std::for_each(std::execution::par, range.begin(), range.end(),
        [&](int i) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            std::ostringstream ss;
            ss << std::this_thread::get_id();
            threads.insert(ss.str());
            values.insert(i);
        });
    std::cout << "Threads:" << std::endl;
    for (auto const & s: threads)
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    {
        bool correct = true;
        size_t cnt = 0;
        for (ptrdiff_t i = start; i < stop; i += step) {
            ++cnt;
            if (!values.count(i)) {
                correct = false;
                std::cout << "No value: " << i << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (values.size() != cnt)
            std::cout << "Expected amount of values: " << cnt
                << ", actual " << values.size() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Correct values: " << std::boolalpha
            << (correct && (values.size() == cnt)) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Threads:
1628
9628
5408
2136
2168
8636
2880
6492
1100
Correct values: true
```

Comment: it is better to mention it is C++20. :)

Comment: @Afshin Question is tagged C++20 tho

Comment: BTW, as this approach is great (I learned something from it myself), it may not be suitable for OP. Since as far as I know, there is no execution mode for ranges, although I may be mistaken. It is somehow obvious that he wants to use `std::execution::par` since it is mentioned in code example.

Comment: @Afshin Thanks for mentioning this parallel execution issue, just updated now my Answer to add solution which allows to use `std::execution::par`.

Comment: It works. But `std::execution::par` doesn't work properly with std::ranges::iota, as [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71705990/is-there-any-equivalent-of-python-range-in-c#comment126725098_71705990) by @康桓瑋.

Comment: @RUSLoker If your mentioned [note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71705990/is-there-any-equivalent-of-python-range-in-c#comment126725098_71705990) is really still true in 2022, then instead of iota I can only suggest hand-made iterator similar to the one [in other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71706094/941531).

Comment: [Still true](https://godbolt.org/z/nKqYvaz73) until [p2408](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2408r4.html) was adopted, the reason why your code compiles is that the libstdc++'s parallel algorithm does not strictly check the iterator category, and the other answer won't work either because it's obviously an input iterator.

Comment: @RUSLoker @康桓瑋 Just updated my answer, with extra code snippet implementing Python-like `Range(start, stop, step)` from scratch. Please put a look. It can be used instead of IOTA, see `main()` function for example of usage.

Comment: `iota` is definitely not "identical" to Python's `range`. `iota` does not have a step options, and `iota(10)` and `range(10)` mean very different things.

Comment: @Barry Thanks for pointing this out. Changed "identical"->"similar".

Comment: @康桓瑋 That's why I told that my implementation is very partial and missing all methods. I only implemented that to make `std::for_each(std::execution::par, ...` compilable. Sure its missing something, but has everything what is needed for this parallel for-each. So you may think of my implementation as not the way to cover all complexity of `Range()`, but as a minimal solution to fit compilation and execution of parallel for-each.

Answer (score 5):

If the problem is in creating range similar to python's `range()` you can look through https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator and use it's example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
 
template<long FROM, long TO>
class Range {
public:
    // member typedefs provided through inheriting from std::iterator
    class iterator: public std::iterator<
                        std::input_iterator_tag,   // iterator_category
                        long,                      // value_type
                        long,                      // difference_type
                        const long*,               // pointer
                        long                       // reference
                                      >{
        long num = FROM;
    public:
        explicit iterator(long _num = 0) : num(_num) {}
        iterator& operator++() {num = TO >= FROM ? num + 1: num - 1; return *this;}
        iterator operator++(int) {iterator retval = *this; ++(*this); return retval;}
        bool operator==(iterator other) const {return num == other.num;}
        bool operator!=(iterator other) const {return !(*this == other);}
        reference operator*() const {return num;}
    };
    iterator begin() {return iterator(FROM);}
    iterator end() {return iterator(TO >= FROM? TO+1 : TO-1);}
};
 
int main() {
    // std::find requires an input iterator
    auto range = Range<15, 25>();
    auto itr = std::find(range.begin(), range.end(), 18);
    std::cout << *itr << '\n'; // 18
 
    // Range::iterator also satisfies range-based for requirements
    for(long l : Range<3, 5>()) {
        std::cout << l << ' '; // 3 4 5
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Although I suggest to write iterator requirements itself without inheriting from `std::iterator` since it is deprecated starting C++17.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative, you could make each work package carry the necessary information by adding the index you need.

Example:

```cpp
std::vector<std::pair<size_t, std::array<float, 2>>> values(1000);
for(size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i) values[i].first = i;

std::for_each(std::execution::par, values.begin(), values.end(),
    [resolution](auto& p) {
        p.second[0] = static_cast<float>(p.first) / resolution;
        p.second[1] = weierstrass(a, b, static_cast<float>(p.first) / resolution);
    });
```

Not using indexing on `values` inside the threaded part like above *may* prevent false sharing and improve performance. You could also make each work package aligned to prevent false sharing to see if that has an effect on performance.

```cpp
#include <new>

struct alignas(std::hardware_destructive_interference_size) workpackage {
    size_t index;
    std::array<float, 2> arr;
};

std::vector<workpackage> values(1000);
for(size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i) values[i].index = i;

std::for_each(std::execution::par, values.begin(), values.end(),
    [resolution](auto& wp) {
        wp.arr[0] = static_cast<float>(wp.index) / resolution;
        wp.arr[1] = weierstrass(a, b, static_cast<float>(wp.index) / resolution);
    });
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, it is not necessary to add index at all. Since `std::for_each` is not allowed to make copies, we can just use a pointer difference to find index.

Comment: @Afshin As I tried to explain in my answer, I tried to stay away from references to `values` (including indexing / pointer arithmetics)  inside the threaded part and to make each work package self sustained since false sharing may happen which may impact performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your code in another way and drop any need for range at all like this:

```cpp
std::vector<std::array<float, 2>> values(1000);

std::for_each(std::execution::par, values.begin(), values.end(), [&](std::array<float, 2>& val) {
    auto i = std::distance(&values[0], &val);
    val[0] = static_cast<float>(i) / resolution;
    val[1] = weierstrass(a, b, static_cast<float>(i) / resolution);
});
```

I should say that this code is valid **if and only if you are using `std::for_each`**, because it is stated that:

> Unlike the rest of the parallel algorithms, `std::for_each` **is not allowed** to make **copies** of the elements in the sequence even if they are trivially copyable.

Comment: `auto i = std::distance(&values[0], &val);` would be an option that keeps compiler warnings about pointer arithmetics away.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I will update it like that. :) Thanks for comment.