# Does Eigen have arange function like numpy.arange() in Python

Tags: python, c++, numpy, eigen

**Do you know if Eigen has its own `arange` function, and if not, why?**

For now, I have written my own arange function using `Eigen::VectorXd::LinSpaced()`

```cpp
/*
* Return evenly spaced values within a given interval.  
* Values are generated within the half-open interval [start, stop) 
* (in other words, the interval including start but excluding stop).
*/
template <typename Scalar>
Eigen::VectorXd arange(const Scalar start, const Scalar stop, const Scalar step) {
  if(step == 0)
    throw std::domain_error("Arange's step cannot be 0");
  Scalar delta = stop - start;
  size_t size = ceil(delta / step);
  return Eigen::VectorXd::LinSpaced(size, start, start+(size-1)*step);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed `LinSpaced` currently available for such an operation, but apparently no direct equivalent of `arange` in Eigen. There are [working notes](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Working_notes_-_Indexing%2B%2B#Arithmetic_progressions_with_explicit-size_.28span.29) related to this (eg. range and iota) but so far nothing appear to be included in the code for that. In the new Eigen 3.4 with a recent C++ version, you can use [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) since Eigen [now support STL iterators](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSTL.html). Thus, there is no real need for a feature like `arange` to be added in Eigen (in fact `LinSpaced` is often good enough for most users).

Comment: As from documentation, `std::iota` fills the range \[first, last\) with sequentially increasing values, starting with value and repetitively evaluating `++value`. It may be required to define a custom `step`, as from third argument of the function described above. For this, an equivalent `arange` function may be useful instead of defining custom functions as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34544665/stdiota-is-very-limited).

Answer (score 0):

A dummy implementation:

```cpp
Eigen::VectorXd arange(double low, double high, double step, bool with_last=false)
{
    int N = static_cast<int>(std::floor((high - low) / step) + 1);
    Eigen::VectorXi V(N);
    std::iota(V.data(), V.data() + N, 0);
    Eigen::VectorXd ret = V.cast<double>();
    ret.array() *= step;
    ret.array() += low;
    if (with_last && ret[N - 1] != high) {
        ret.conservativeResize(N + 1);
        ret[N] = high;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

test:

```cpp
ASSERT_EQ(arange(0, 1, 0.25), (Eigen::VectorXd(4) << 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0).finished());
ASSERT_EQ(arange(0, 1, 0.25 - 1e-3).size(), 5);
ASSERT_EQ(arange(0, 1, 0.25 - 1e-3, true).size(), 6);
ASSERT_EQ(arange(1, 0, -0.25), (Eigen::VectorXd(4) << 1, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 0.0).finished());
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier implementation from previous answers: calculate `N` and then use `Eigen::LinSpaced`:

```
typedef Eigen::VectorXd vec;

vec arange(double low, double high, double step, bool with_last = false)
{
    high -= (with_last) ? 0 : step;
    int N = static_cast<int>(std::floor((high - low) / step) + 1);
    return vec::LinSpaced(N, low, high);
}
```

You can then enhance with some validity check over the parameters passed