# How to lazily generate a finished sequence of items and iterate over it

Tags: c++, iterator

I feel like this question must have been asked and solved many times, because this seems to me a quite generic scenario, but I could not find anything that pointed me in the direction of a solution.

I'm trying to implement a generic iterable `Generator` object that produces a sequence of numbers up until a certain termination condition is met, signaling that such condition has been reached in order to stop the iteration.

The basic idea is, essentially, to have something similar to Python's generators where an object yields values until it has no more to yield and then a `StopIteration` exception is raised to inform the outside loop that the sequence is finished.

From what I understand, the problem splits into creating the sequence-generating object an then obtaining an iterator over it.

For the sequence-generating object, I thought I'd define a base `Generator` class which is then extended to provide specific behaviours (e.g., get values from a set of ranges, or from a list of fixed values, etc). All `Generaor`s produce a new value at each call of `operator()` or throw a `ValuesFinishedException` if the generator ran to the end of the sequence.
I implemented this as such (I show the single-range subclass as example, but I need to be able to model more types of sequences):

```
struct ValuesFinishedException : public std::exception { };

template <typename T>
class Generator
{
public:
    Generator() { };
    ~Generator() { };
    virtual T operator()() = 0; // return the new number or raise a ValuesFinishedException
};

template <typename T>
class RangeGenerator : public Generator<T>
{
private:
    T m_start;
    T m_stop;
    T m_step;

    T m_next_val;

public:
    RangeGenerator(T start, T stop, T step) :
        m_start(start),
        m_stop(stop),
        m_step(step),
        m_next_val(start)
    { }

    T operator()() override
    {
        if (m_next_val >= m_stop)
            throw ValuesFinishedException();

        T retval = m_next_val;
        m_next_val += m_step;
        return retval;
    }

    void setStep(T step) { m_step = step; }
    T step() { return m_step; }
};
```

For the iterator part, though, I'm stuck.
I have researched any combination I could think of of "Iterator", "Generator" and synonyms, but all I find only considers the case where a generator function has an unlimited number of values (see for example [boost's generator_iterator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/iterator/doc/generator_iterator.htm)). I thought about writing a `Generator::iterator` class myself, but I only found examples of trivial iterators (linked lists, array reimplementations) where `end` is well-defined. I don't know in advance when the end will be reached, I only know that if the generator I'm iterating over raises the exception, I need to set the iterator's current value to "end()", but I don't know how to represent it.

### Edit: Adding the intended use-case

The reason for this class is to have a flexible sequence object I can loop over:

```
RangeGenerator gen(0.25f, 95.3f, 1.2f);
for(auto v : gen)
{
    // do something with v
}
```

The example of the range is just the simplest one. I will have at least three actual use-cases:

- simple range (with variable step)
- concatenation of multiple ranges
- sequence of constant values stored in a vector

For each of these I'm planning on having a `Generator` subclass, with the iterator defined for the abstract `Generator`.

Comment: Just have a sentinel state for your iterator representing "end", and write your comparison operator so `i == end` is only true if `i` has reached it's terminal condition. This can be as simple as adding a `bool isAtEnd` member. Don't use an exception, that's importing a Python convention to C++

Comment: Yeah, I felt that using the exception was bad practice, but coming from Python I went for the solution I knew. The thing is, IMO the exception cleanly separates the "there is another value in the sequence" case from "the sequence is over". How would I notify someone calling `generator()` that that instance actually ran through the whole sequence without the exception? I can't assume I always have a value to return... (writing this I'm thinking of `std::optional<T>` as return value for `operator()`.. would that be any better?)

Comment: I think you're trying to model Python too closely, which is why you're now having trouble matching up a Python generator to a C++ iterator. Iterators in C++ don't call until exception, you compare them. Your "end" iterator is one where `m_next_val == m_stop`. You will also need to write an equality method to check for this.

Comment: If you want to generate infinite sequences, do you need the iterator interface at all? When you get an iterator, what will you do next with it? (i.e. the use-case)

Comment: @Hitobat Same thing you do in other languages, for example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n

Comment: just an idea: you could have a sentinal value for the `end` iterator (as I understood you dont know where the end is unless you are there) and then make the iterators `operator==` behave differently when one of the operands is `end` (ie ignore the `end` operand and only check if the other has a next element, if not it is equal to `end`)

Comment: @Hitobat see my edit

Comment: Have you had a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368949/cycles-in-c-like-in-python-range-based-for)?

Comment: haha just realized that my idea wasnt that new, but @Useless basically suggested the same

Comment: @lubgr no, I didn't find that! It looks very close to what I need (at least for the simple-range case) but I think I can adapt it for the other cases as well. thanks for pointing me to it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the generic generator you originally asked for (rather than the simpler use-cases added later), it *is* possible to set up something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Generator {
    Generator() {}
    explicit Generator(std::function<std::optional<T>()> f_) : f(f_), v(f()) {}

    Generator(Generator<T> const &) = default;
    Generator(Generator<T> &&) = default;
    Generator<T>& operator=(Generator<T> const &) = default;
    Generator<T>& operator=(Generator<T> &&) = default;

    bool operator==(Generator<T> const &rhs) {
        return (!v) && (!rhs.v); // only compare equal if both at end
    }
    bool operator!=(Generator<T> const &rhs) { return !(*this == rhs); }

    Generator<T>& operator++() {
        v = f();
        return *this;
    }
    Generator<T> operator++(int) {
        auto tmp = *this;
        ++*this;
        return tmp;
    }

    // throw `std::bad_optional_access` if you try to dereference an end iterator
    T const& operator*() const {
        return v.value();
    }

private:
    std::function<std::optional<T>()> f;
    std::optional<T> v;
};
```

if you have C++17 (if you don't, use Boost or just track validity manually). The begin/end functions needed to use this nicely look something like

```
template <typename T>
Generator<T> generate_begin(std::function<std::optional<T>()> f) { return Generator<T>(f); }
template <typename T>
Generator<T> generate_end(std::function<std::optional<T>()>) { return Generator<T>(); }
```

Now for a suitable function `foo` you can use this like a normal input operator:

```
auto sum = std::accumulate(generate_begin(foo), generate_end(foo), 0);
```

I omitted the iterator traits which should be defined in `Generator` as they are in YSC's answer- they should be something like the below (and `operator*` should return `reference`, and you should add `operator->`, etc. etc.)

```
    // iterator traits
    using difference_type = int;
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = const T*;
    using reference = const T&;
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the closest I've seen so far to what I originally needed. While the other answers do provide a solution to the simpler sub-problems, I'd rather have a a generic solution that works with any functor. I'll need some time to understand your code, but I believe this is pretty much what I need

Comment: Note that if your generator function is more naturally written as throwing an exception or returning some sentinel value, you can easily write an adapter function to turn it into the required `std::optional` form.

Comment: About the iterator traits, YSC shows them for type `int`. Using the generic type T what would `difference_type` be? Should I still use int? Or `std::ptrdiff_t` as I've seen in some examples? Also, do I uderstand it correctly that in my case an `input_iterator_tag` would be the right choice? (forward iterator requires the values to be modifiable, which is not my case)

Comment: Correct, it's an input iterator (the function could be stateful, so we can only assume single-pass). For the difference type, `int` or `size_t` are fine. Mostly I didn't write them because value_type, reference_type and pointer_type need reference removal to be completely safe (a function could return optional<reference_wrapper<T>> to externally-stored persistent objects).

Comment: I'm not sure I get the part about reference removal (template programming is almost entirely new to me), but I plan on using the classes only with simple types (most likely just floats) at least for now, so I believe I can ignore that part. As per the difference type, does it need to be signed? (if so, `size_t` won't work)

Comment: Just tested your code and it works like a charm, thank you *very* much for helping me solve this problem in an elegant way (and teaching me a thing or two while doing so)

Answer (score 5):

You should use a C++ idiom: the forward iterator. This let you use C++ syntactic sugar and support the standard library. Here is a minimal example:

```
template<int tstart, int tstop, int tstep = 1>
class Range {
public:
    class iterator {
        int start;
        int stop;
        int step;
        int current;
    public:
        iterator(int start, int stop, int step = 0, int current = tstart) : start(start), stop(stop), step(step == 0 ? (start < stop ? 1 : -1) : step), current(current) {}
        iterator& operator++() {current += step; return *this;}
        iterator operator++(int) {iterator retval = *this; ++(*this); return retval;}
        bool operator==(iterator other) const {return std::tie(current, step, stop) == std::tie(other.current, other.step, other.stop);}
        bool operator!=(iterator other) const {return !(*this == other);}
        long operator*() {return current;}
        // iterator traits
        using difference_type = int;
        using value_type = int;
        using pointer = const int*;
        using reference = const int&;
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    };
    iterator begin() {return iterator{tstart, tstop, tstep};}
    iterator end() {return iterator{tstart, tstop, tstep, tstop};}
};
```

It can be used with the C++98 way:

```
using range = Range<0, 10, 2>;
auto r = range{};
for (range::iterator it = r.begin() ; it != r.end() ; ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << '\n';
}
```

Or with the new range loop:

```
for (auto n : Range<0, 10, 2>{}) {
    std::cout << n << '\n';
}
```

In cunjunction with the stl:

```
std::copy(std::begin(r), std::end(r), std::back_inserter(v));
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35ad4ce16428e65d

Comment: You don't need the `start`, `stop`, `step` members, since those values are template parameters. You also don't need to compare `step` and `stop`, since those can only be different for a different instantiation.

Comment: @molbdnilo I agree. In fact, that iterator would need additional enhancements before it starts being useful. This is just a example to avoid complex and long explanations.

Answer (score 2):

The range based for loop is all about the iterator implementing begin(), end() and operator++.

So the generator must implement them.

```
template<typename T>
struct generator {
    T first;
    T last;

    struct iterator {
        using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = T;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using pointer = T *;
        using reference = T &;
        T value;

        iterator(T &value) : value(value) {}

        iterator &operator++() {
            ++value;
            return *this;
        }
        iterator operator++(int) = delete;

        bool operator==(const iterator &rhs) { return value == rhs.value; }
        bool operator!=(const iterator &rhs) { return !(*this == rhs); }
        const reference operator *() { return value; }
        const pointer operator->() const { return std::addressof(value); }
    };

    iterator begin() { return iterator(first); }
    iterator end() { return iterator(last); }
};
```

Then add a function which instantiates the generator and you are done

```
template<typename T>
generator<T> range(T start, T end) {
    return generator<T>{ start, end };
}

for (auto i : range(0, 10))
{
}
```

Comment: I read it was deprecated in C++17 already (although tbh I can live with that for now)

Answer (score 1):

The use case you describe (concatenation of ranges etc.) might justify a dependency on a library, so here is a solution based on [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/), on its way into C++20. You can easily iterate through integral values, here from 0 to 10 with a step size of 2,

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

using namespace ranges;

for (auto i : view::ints(0, 11) | view::stride(2))
   std::cout << i << "\n";
```

or implement a similar loop with floating point values (note that [from, to] is a closed range here, and the third argument denotes the number of steps)

```
for (auto f : view::linear_distribute(1.25f, 2.5f, 10))
   std::cout << f << "\n";
```

and when it comes to concatenation, the library begins to shine:

```
const std::vector world{32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100};

for (auto i : view::concat("hello", world))
   std::cout << char(i);

std::cout << "\n";
```

Note that the above snippets compile with `-std=c++17`. The library is header only.

Comment: This looks great and I wish that was included in the standard already, but currently this is out of reach for me sadly. Also, I need to be able to alter the step while iterating over floats, which I think this doesn't support (although I haven't looked in depth into the library)